# jquery ajax call return type

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

I tested one ajax call in two different pages of a Spring MVC project: 
    The first page is kind of the simple page has only two drop down lists, select the 1st dropdown item, then it will make the ajax call to database and load the data into the 2nd dropdown list.
    The second page has more items but the two dropdown lists are same as the 1st page. However, the call in this page always failed.

The ajax function like:

```
$.ajax({
                        url : 'ajaxTest.html',
                        data: dataString,//The params
                            dataType: "json",
                        success : function(data) {
                            $('#result').empty();
                            $(data).each(function(i){
                                 $('#result').append("<option value='" +data[i].corr_no+"'>" + data[i].local_no+"</option>");
                             });
                        },
                        error: function (data) {// When Service call fails
                            alert('Service call failed: ' + data.status + ' ' + data.statusText);
                        }
                         });
```

By using firebug, looks the 2nd page cannot parse the data returned from ajax call because it returned all of the page. Since the calls in two pages are calling the same controller method, I have no idea where is wrong. Need suggestion to fix it. If any library or path setup will effect the ajax function's data return? Or how to debug this kind of issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the success callback getting called or not? Open console, check in network tab for error (maybe relative URL issue). If success is called, check what `data` you get

Comment: The success callback called!. I added one alert message there. But by checking the firebug, the returned data is the whole page.

Comment: This problem has been fixed like: url : '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ajaxTest.html',